# Vanilla JS Typerror: 'Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getBoundingClientRect') | Why?

Tags: javascript, function, game-physics

Im trying to code a 2d game with javascript and I'm working on a position system in which if the user character overlaps the coin, a value changes. Im using .getBoundingClientRect() to get position and the function itself is fine. But anytime I add in an if statement that says if the function is true, (which it is), it gives me this error. Any ways to fix? (Attached code screenshots)

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5pTsj.png)
[Chrome Console Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yxmsT.png)

Comment: on line 67 you are not passing the parameters

Comment: Please provide code snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `elementsOverlap` accepts 2 parameters, none of which you have provided while calling it.

And given that `user` is one of those parameters, the function will not use the `user` variable in the global scope. It will use the `user` parameter which is supposed to have been provided.

try removing the parameters since they're global anyway:

```
function elementOverlap(){
    // ... your code
}
```

Comment: thanks so much, it worked! I spent like a good hour racking my brain around it. Pretty easy to tell I only got into js a few weeks ago lol

Answer (score 0):

```
const handleScroll = () => {
      if(!ref.current) return
      if (ref.current.getBoundingClientRect().y <= -580 || null) 
  {
    console.log(ref.current.getBoundingClientRect().y);
    setSticky(true);
  } 
  else {
    setSticky(false);
  }
};
```

refs can be null on rerenders therefore always null check before accessing properties of elements refs. Here is what gaearon has to say about refs.